# New membership confirmation e-mail not sent for free memberships?

Tags: civimember, email

I'm experimenting with Memberships for the first time, entering them manually, and it looks like just ticking "Send Confirmation and Receipt?" isn't sufficient for a contact to receive an e-mail confirmation of their membership. The e-mail doesn't arrive unless "Record Membership Payment?" is also ticked. Is that the intended behaviour?

It seems kinda counter intuitive that members won't receive a confirmation e-mail unless I enter a payment of £0 on their record, and send them a receipt for it...